# How to connect Raspberry pi 3 Model B+ with P10 outdoor single RED color LED module (p10-smd-4s-v9-5)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

enter image description here

[This is HUB12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBDQD.jpg)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about hardware. Probably belongs on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled around a bit and https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix seems to deal with that model (even if the name says "rgb").

It has docs on wiring too: https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/blob/master/wiring.md

(Yes, I'm aware this is basically a link-only answer, but reproducing the wiring diagrams and all from Github wouldn't seem appropriate copyright-wise.)